# test input of jest test is not converting on to the json file

Tags: jestjs, command-line-interface

`jest --json --outputFile=tests.json` is not producing tests.json file and test runs fine so no problem at that front. I have `21.2.1` version of the jest.

I am getting this in terminal:

> Please run 'npm install' to use the version of Jest intended for this project.

Accroding to [Jest changelog](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) `--json --outputFile` command is supported from version `18.0.0` so I don't think version is problem.